# SQL Server 2005 Maintenance Plan w/ Full and Transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to create Maintenance Plan to backup my database in SQL 2005. SQL 2005 does not have the option of setting a different schedules for Full Backup and Transaction log. Should I create two different maintenance plans to accomplish my goal of having my database do a FULL backup each night at midnight and a `TRANSACTION LOG` backup every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

No need to add a separate maintenance plan. In SSMS Maintenance Plan designer you can add a Subplan to do your trans log backups with any schedule you want, independent of other Subplans.  It will add a separate SQL Agent job for the subplan.